# non-static variable cannot this be referenced from a static context error

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter expression: ");
String exp = input.nextLine().trim();

ExpressionTree exptree = new ExpressionTree1(); //new instance of ExpressionTree
TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
root = exptree.parseOutsideExpression(exp);
int evaluate = exptree.Compute(root);
String answer = Integer.toString(evaluate);
System.out.println("The evaluated expression is:" + answer);

}

class ExpressionTree{
```

I've looked at several examples and I've noticed that a common answer is to create a new instance of your object within main() which I've done, but I still get the same error and I am unclear as to why.

Comment: What line are you getting the error at? What are the contents of that line?

Comment: You can remove  reeNode root = new TreeNode();
if you are just going to reasign it one line later

Comment: you need to have your main method inside some class

Comment: @codeMan The main method is; we just don't need to know any such name. If it wasn't in a class, it wouldn't even run, so he wouldn't even be asking this question.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu yeah, I agree with u. I was wondering what the line `class ExpressionTree{` at the end mean??

Comment: @codeMan That doesn't have to be in the same code block. He has another class called ExpressionTree.

Comment: On what line do you get the copmiler error?

Comment: I accidentally had a 1 at the end of the ExpressionTree when I created a new instance. The problem was that because it was an inner class I had to make it static. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `ExpressionTree` is an inner class of the same class with the `main()` method, maybe the problem is that it's not static. Non-static inner classes can only be instantiated in non-static code... see:

> [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)